# Magento 2 : Error While upgrade 2.3.0 to 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0, magento2.3.1

I am trying to upgrade Magento version from 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 and I am using PHP 7.2 for same but while I run upgrade command getting bellow error is anyone have any idea how to fix?

```
   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php on line 55


    Warning: Unsupported declare 'strict_types' in /vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php on line 6

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or '{' in /vendor/magento/inventory-composer-installer/src/Plugin.php on line 55
```

[image]

Comment: Magento 2.3.1 is compatible with 7.2.x only

Comment: i also try to update at 7.2.x still also same error

Comment: Magento 2.3.1 is compatible with PHP 7.2.x and one more thing have you checked your php version in command interface using `php -v` ?

Comment: Can you please share your console screenshot?

Comment: added, please check

Answer (score 1):

it was due to a server issue, when I run **composer update** command it taking wrong PHP version due to some server configuration. so I just download composer.phar file for run composer update using PHP version and it worked. for me, bellow command working
**php composer.phar update**

**Magento 2.3.1 required php 7.1 version if version is less then php 7.1 then it give error in my case default php version was 5.6 something so it giving error**

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not require PHP 7.2 since 2.3.1 release, PHP 7.1.3 and later still supported. 
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

in your case, the system has a fatal error encountering `void` return type
https://github.com/magento-engcom/inventory-composer-installer/blob/master/src/Plugin.php#L55

Which is added since PHP 7.1 release - https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php